# How to access FormData sent with javascript vanilla in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, blob, multipartform-data

I have this simple program that saves `canvas` into `blob file`, I am trying to retrieve it in **php**, but I can't manage to access it.

My `console.log(FormData)` does show the **blob** file content properly.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="formId">
    <button id="click-photo" type="submit" value="submit">Click Photo</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var image_data_url = "";
    xhr.open('POST', 'image.php', true);
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
            alert(xhr.reponseText);
        };
    };
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    var file = dataURLtoBlob( canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') );;
    
    const fd = new FormData;
    fd.append('image', file);
    xhr.send(fd);
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['image'])){
        print_r ($_FILES['image']);
    };
?>
```

Comment: The problem isn't the retrieving in PHP, the problem is that you are not processing PHP's response to your XMLHttpRequest. You need to do `xhr.onreadystatechange = ...` to assign a handler that displays / logs the response. The browser does not navigate to the result of an AJAX request.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` requests need a boundary, but you did not specify one. Remove that header; based on what the FormData actually contains, browsers should be able to set the correct Content-Type header on their own.

Comment: @ChrisG If you may explain more of what should be appended from the code inside ```onreadystatechange``` I am a bit new to ```Ajax``` so I am confusing things a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: May I point you to the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readystatechange_event#examples

Comment: @ChrisG after appending starting from ```canvas.getContext``` now my ```formData``` is **null** outside the state.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect your code changes. And formData being null is probably just this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: @ChrisG the new edits are there now :)

Comment: Right, you completely misunderstood how onreadystatechange works. Move the code back outside where it used to be, it was fine there. Now inside the `if (status == ...` block, just do this: `alert(xhr.reponseText);`. That is whatever your PHP code sends back as response to your request.

Comment: @ChrisG fixed that, and now actually after checking my network tab, I am receiving from **php** the right respond, but it's not being echoed into the **HTML**

Comment: Like I said almost an hour ago: "The browser does not navigate to the result of an AJAX request.". If you want to display the result in your HTML somewhere you need to actually write code that does that. Something like `document.getElementById('result').innerText = xhr.reponseText;`

Comment: @ChrisG I have tried all those ways, and yet seems not to be working :) except if you are really busy, It would be nice to see a full written solution. But thanks anyway for your words

Comment: To trivially solve this problem, use `<form id="imgForm" method="post" action="image.php">`. Now add a submit event listener to the form, and inside turn the canvas content into a base64 string and put the result as .value of an `<input type="hidden" name="base64image">`. Submitting the form will now populate the hidden input first, and your PHP code can simply read `$_POST['base64image']` and output HTML as usual. (i.e. you can get rid of all the xhr code)

Comment: Also, regarding my previous comment, you obviously need a `<div id="result"></div>` for that to work.

Comment: @ChrisG This solution you wrote was quite great and works now, I have implemented it, I was only trying to do so Async so the page wouldn't refresh, but I guess I will try to read more still about that first and for now use this solution.

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh, then AJAX/xhr/fetch is the way to go, but displaying the result will require manually inserting it into the DOM in that case. That's a really basic thing to do, so if that was all that didn't work I encourage you to go back to ajax. And use fetch().

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the image with a different name than the one you are trying to retrieve.

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var image_data_url = "";
    xhr.open('POST', 'image.php', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
                alert(xhr.reponseText);
            };
        };
    }

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    var file = dataURLtoBlob( canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') );;
    
    const fd = new FormData;
    fd.append('image', file);
    xhr.send(fd);
});
```

```php
// ...
if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
// Up here it should be: if (isset($_FILES['image'])){
// ...
```

Comment: Tried with image still not receiving anything

Comment: I've never worked with canvas, but I think `$_FILES` is more for uploading files coming from `<input type="file" />`. Try changing it to `$_POST['image']`.

Comment: Changed both sir and yet not reacting at all

Comment: Did you see in the browser console network requests if this data is being sent normally?

Comment: Actually I didn't, but now going back to the old code, I am actually able to see in my network response the right data, it's only not being echoed for the HTML for some reason!

Comment: This is just a typo; the actual issue is OP not handling the response of their AJAX request.

Comment: To work with the response coming from the server you need to do as @ChrisG said and implement `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: You're just rehashing the docs though? And OP should use fetch() instead anyway.